# How to develop multi admin application with rails and cancan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan, cancancan

I have next model of roles:

```
Admin1 -> Manager1 -> User1
      |
       -> Manager2 -> User2
                  |
                   -> User3

Admin2 -> Manager3 -> User4
      |
       -> Manager4 -> User5
                  |
                   -> User6
```

Admin1 can create Manager1, Manager1 can create User1.
Admin1 should have ability manage all Manager1 and Manager2 resources and resources of nested users User1,2,3. Manager1 should manage own resources and Resources of User1,2.

Admin2 should not be able made any action on Admin1, Manager1,2 and User1,2,3 resources.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a field to your user model, say user_creator, which holds a reference to the user which created that user. Then just make sure that users can only manage/administrate other users that they have created or that have been created by a user which they have created (using cancancan). This should achieve what you are looking for.
You can then check if the current user is able to manage/administrate the other user, with something like:

```
def sub_user_or_sub_sub_user_of?(user) 
  if self.sub_users.include?(user)
    true
  else self.sub_users.each do |sub_user|
     return true if sub_user.sub_users.include?(user)
    end
  end
end
```